# IE problems with JCrop

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, jcrop

I am using jcrop with my aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Scripts/css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css" />
```

Here is my JCrop declaration:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#' + options.ImageID).Jcrop({
            onChange: function (coords) {
                $('#' + options.HiddenID).val(coords.x + ',' + coords.y + ',' + coords.w + ',' + coords.h);
            },
            aspectRatio: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my .NET image:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="PhotoPreviewImage" />
```

The options variable is an object created in the code behind to pass the ClientID of PhotoPreviewImage to the JS.

This works great in Chrome, it doesn't work in IE9 (I don't even get the crosshairs).

I am using jquery.Jcrop.min.js v0.9.10 (build:20120429) and jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com

How can I make this work in IE?

Comment: do you get any javascript errors ?

Comment: @Aristos - nothing that I can see :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some issues with JCrop in IE in the past. I solved it by adding the "onSelect" and "onRelease" events to the options object.  I don't know if this will help you in your situation but its worth a shot.  My code looked like this:

.Net

```
<asp:Image ID="cropbox" runat="server" ImageUrl="Assets/images/blank.gif" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var api = $.Jcrop('#cropbox', {
        aspectRatio: 1,
        onSelect: update,
        onChange: update,
        onRelease: update
    });
});

function update(c) {
    //Store coords here
}
</script>
```

Comment: I had to modify this to pass in the ClientID rather than the ID of the .NET Image control but other than that worked great!  Edited to add this appears to break it in Chrome, however I can work around that!

Comment: This got it working for me in IE, but broke Safari. I ended up having to detect browser and use API method (similar to above, the only difference is I moved all of the options to a separate function) for IE and the [normal way](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html) for all other browsers... seems to be working consistently across all browsers.

Answer (score 7):

I ended up having to detect IE and use one of two formats to initialize:

```
        var is_msie = /msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
        var jcrop_obj;

        if (is_msie) {
            jcrop_obj = jQuery.Jcrop('#img', {
                onSelect: jcrop_onEndCrop,
                minSize: [ 20, 20 ],
                setSelect: [ x, y, x2, y2 ],
                allowSelect: false
            });
        }
        else {
            jQuery('#img').Jcrop({
                onSelect: jcrop_onEndCrop,
                minSize: [ 20, 20 ],
                setSelect: [ x, y, x2, y2 ],
                allowSelect: false
            },function(){jcrop_obj = this;});
        }
```

Comment: Just had to drop a comment, 5 hours of figuring out why jCrop only initialized after a few refreshes on IE and this fixed it all :)

Comment: you, sir, are a hero. 
but why check browser instead of just always using the IE version?

Comment: @ThomasStock: The IE version does not work on Chrome.

Comment: hmm it works here after testing 5 times. Does it "sometimes" not work?

Comment: @ThomasStock: Instantiating jcrop was not my problem, but I had to dynamically switch the image and reset the instance of jcrop.  If I remember right, the jcrop_obj did not always contain the reference until I implemented the above.

Answer (score -1):

This definitely fixed initialization for IE 10 Compatibility mode.

Comment: Not sure what your answer means though.